# WinJs xhr getting error The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource

Tags: json, winjs

WinJs xhr getting error The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource,
I am sending json to a webapi , I have set the header to application/json so I was not expecting this error. 
any help here thanks

```
                  WinJS.xhr(
                { url: "http://api.xxxxxx.com.au/api/jobs/GetNearActiveJobs", type: "POST", responseType: "json", data: { LocationId: 23555, kms: 10 }, headers: { contentType: "application/json" } } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WinJS.xhr({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://api.xxxxxx.com.au/api/jobs/GetNearActiveJobs",
        headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
        data: JSON.stringify({ LocationId: 23555, kms: 10 })
    })
```